# Calculate odds some $n$ numbers, picked from the same uniform distribution, occurring within some interval of eachother

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Consider three sets of random numbers, $A,B$ and $C$, with known sizes $p,q,r$, picked from the same uniform distribution on $[x,y]$. What is the probability of an $a\in A$, $b\in B$, and $c\in C$ (picked at random) being within some $\Delta$-wide window of each other, knowing the size of each set?

Comment: I'm not sure how having distinct sets of random numbers applies here. Do you mean that there are sets $A,B,C$ containing elements $a_1,\dots,a_k\in A,b_1,\dots,b_m\in B,c_1,\dots,c_n\in C$ and you want to calculate the probability that for some $x$, you have $(x,x+\delta)\cap A, (x,x+\delta)\cap B, (x,x+\Delta)\cap C$ all nonempty (i.e., considering every possible sample), or are you simply asking for the probability that three values from a continuous uniform distribution will land within $\Delta$ of each other (i.e. taking a single sample)?

Comment: @NicoTerry I'm talking about the latter. As you point out, I'm pretty sure the fact that I'm working with three distinct sets doesn't matter, since they're from the same distribution, however I included this detail in the case that I'm wrong.

Comment: I was asking *how* it applied, not why or whether it would matter, because if you take $|A|+|B|+|C|$ values and ask whether three of them are within a $\Delta$-wide window of each other, that probability increases much more quickly than having one $a\in A,b\in B,c\in C$ from each set, which itself increases substantially based on the size of the sets (if you have a distribution on $[0,1]$, which you can always normalize to, you have a much higher chance of meeting your condition if $A,B,C$ are large than if they contain only a few elements apiece).

Comment: @NicoTerry Apologies for being dumb here... I'm referring to the second. I have three sets, call them $A,B,C$, with known sizes $n,m,p$, where the elements in each set are picked from the same uniform distribution on $[x,y]$ (which, as you point out, can be normalized to $[0,1]$). So, the question is, what is the probability of an $a\in A$, $b\in B$, and $c\in C$ being within a $\Delta$-wide window of each other, knowing the sizes of $A,B$ and $C$.

Comment: @NicoTerry I'll clarify above, as well.